# pandas dataframe change backgroundcolor on conditions and save outcome in html

Tags: python, pandas, colors, cell

I have a dataframe with following columns: `DIVISION,MONTH,YEAR,RANGE,CABIN,BP_TYPE` and than 6 columns with float values from the previous days
as example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DIVISION': ['FRA', 'FRA', 'FRA', 'FRA', 'FRA'],
                   'MONTH': ['FEB', 'FEB', 'FEB', 'FEB', 'FEB'],
                   'YEAR': [2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023],
                   'RANGE': ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'I'],
                   'CABIN': ['C', 'C', 'M', 'M', 'C'],
                   'BP_TYPE': ['SYS', 'USR', 'SYS', 'USR', 'SYS'],
                   '2023-01-27': [60.92, 64.89, 112.47, 112.47, 779.78],
                   '2023-01-28': [63.18, 66.76, 132.17, 132.17, 763.60],
                   '2023-01-29': [61.95, 64.94, 129.21, 129.21, 753.88],
                   '2023-01-30': [59.40, 62.09, 118.04, 118.04, 720.08],
                   '2023-01-31': [52.69, 55.53, 104.28, 104.28, 687.73],
                   '2023-02-01': [85.56, 89.64, 123.53, 124.62, 789.50]})
```

now i want to change the background color like:
compare starting from column 7 value with previous value and if

```
"Deviation > +5%: red
Deviation < -5%: blue
Deviation > +2,5% and <= +5%: lightred
Deviation < -2,5% and >= -5%: lightblue"
```

i tried it this way but without success:

```
def color_cell(val):
    color = 'green'
    if val > 0:
        if val > 0.01:
            color = 'red'
        elif val > 0.025:
            color = 'lightred'
    elif val < 0:
        if val < -0.01:
            color = 'blue'
        elif val < -0.025:
            color = 'lightblue'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

df_style = df.style.apply(color_cell, axis=1, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, 6:])
```

or

```
df_style = df_pivot.iloc[:, 6:].style.applymap(color_cell).render()
```

without succeed

later on I need to safe this in html:

```
html_content = df_style.render().to_html()
with open("color.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(html_content)
```

can someone pls help me?

mozway where is my error?:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'DIVISION': ['FRA', 'FRA', 'FRA', 'FRA', 'FRA'],
                   'MONTH': ['FEB', 'FEB', 'FEB', 'FEB', 'FEB'],
                   'YEAR': [2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023],
                   'RANGE': ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'I'],
                   'CABIN': ['C', 'C', 'M', 'M', 'C'],
                   'BP_TYPE': ['SYS', 'USR', 'SYS', 'USR', 'SYS'],
                   '2023-01-27': [60.92, 64.89, 112.47, 112.47, 779.78],
                   '2023-01-28': [63.18, 66.76, 132.17, 132.17, 763.60],
                   '2023-01-29': [61.95, 64.94, 129.21, 129.21, 753.88],
                   '2023-01-30': [59.40, 62.09, 118.04, 118.04, 720.08],
                   '2023-01-31': [52.69, 55.53, 104.28, 104.28, 687.73],
                   '2023-02-01': [85.56, 89.64, 123.53, 124.62, 789.50]})

bins = np.array([-np.inf, -5, -2.5, 2.5, 5, np.inf])/100
labels = ['background-color: blue', 'background-color: lightblue', '', 'background-color: lightred', 'background-color: red']

def color(df):
    return (df.drop(columns=['DIVISION', 'MONTH', 'YEAR', 'RANGE', 'CABIN', 'BP_TYPE'])
              .pct_change(axis=1).apply(lambda s: pd.cut(s, bins=bins, labels=labels), )
              .reindex_like(df)
            )

html = (df.style.apply(color, axis=1, subset=df.columns[7:]).to_html())

with open('table.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./test.py", line 28, in 
html = (df.style.apply(color, axis=1, subset=df.columns[7:]).to_html())
AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'to_html'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`style.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply) with help of [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) and [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
bins = np.array([-np.inf, -5, -2.5, 2.5, 5, np.inf])/100
labels = ['background-color: blue', 'background-color: lightblue', '', 'background-color: lightred', 'background-color: red']

def color(df):
    return (df.drop(columns=['DIVISION', 'MONTH', 'YEAR', 'RANGE', 'CABIN', 'BP_TYPE'])
              .pct_change(axis=1).apply(lambda s: pd.cut(s, bins=bins, labels=labels), )
              .reindex_like(df)
            )

df.style.apply(color, axis=None)
```

Or with [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to select the date like headers:

```
bins = np.array([-np.inf, -5, -2.5, 2.5, 5, np.inf])/100
labels = ['background-color: blue', 'background-color: lightblue', '', 'background-color: lightred', 'background-color: red']

def color(df):
    return (df.filter(regex=r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
              .pct_change(axis=1).apply(lambda s: pd.cut(s, bins=bins, labels=labels), )
              .reindex_like(df)
            )

df.style.apply(color, axis=None)
```

Alternative using a row-wise function:

```
bins = np.array([-np.inf, -5, -2.5, 2.5, 5, np.inf])/100
labels = ['background-color: blue', 'background-color: lightblue', '', 'background-color: lightred', 'background-color: red']

def color_row(row):
    return pd.cut(row.pct_change(), bins=bins, labels=labels)

df.style.apply(color_row, axis=1, subset=df.columns[7:])
```

Output:

[image]

##### as HTML

```
html = (
 df.style.apply(color_cell, axis=1, subset=df.columns[7:])
   .to_html()
)

with open('table.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Comment: many thanks mozzy ... unfortunately the code is not running at my environment ( linux) do i need to install Jinja2 for this?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you have a warning or error?

Comment: i used your code and added it:

bins = np.array([-np.inf, -5, -2.5, 2.5, 5, np.inf])/100
labels = ['background-color: blue', 'background-color: lightblue', '', 'background-color: lightred', 'background-color: red']

def color_row(row):
    return pd.cut(row.pct_change(), bins=bins, labels=labels)

df_pivot.style.apply(color_row, axis=1, subset=df.columns[7:])


print(df_pivot)

html_content = df_pivot.to_html()
with open('/app/datahub/web/FRA_1.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html_content)

at webpage I cannot see any color ... so I guess some library's are missing

Comment: `style` is not in place, you need to chain the `to_html` directly after it: `df.style.apply(...).to_html(...)`

Comment: can you pls help me with this line in my case ... i have no experience with style and write to_html ( I'm a beginner ;-))

Comment: if I try this:
df = df_pivot.style.apply(color_row, axis=1, subset=df.columns[7:]).to_html()

with open('/app/datahub/web/FRA_1.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df)
i receive AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'to_html'

Comment: sorry mozway ...still not working for me - pls see my update above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251569/discussion-between-glammy-and-mozway).

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on. Can you try in a notebook or on a different computer? What are your python/pandas versions? It's almost certainly not an issue with the code but rather with the setup of your environment.